# Set all workitems to inactive when one is set to active

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I would like to know if it is possible to set other tasks to "pending" or "inactive"  when the user (contributor) set one to active.

I was wondering if i can do that using Workflow or another kind of customization in TFS.

Regards

Comment: What is the scope of the other work items that you want to modify? (e.g., all tasks in the current iteration) What process template are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that if you use the product as it is...

Back in the days of TFS 2005/2008 I wrote [a tool](http://wicreator.codeplex.com/) to do what you need with very complex possibilities of workflow between work items, but I didn't have the time to rewrite it for 2010 (the typed links introduced in 2010 would change a lot of things).

If you're not afraid to write a custom tool you can read [this post](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=336) and the source code of my codeplex project.